# XCODE 4.3.2 in SQL LITE How to write ' LIKE ' Keyword

Tags: iphone

Iphone
Currently I am writing my query like this

rs=[db executeQuery:@"SELECT * from FormData where flgActive=1 and FirstName like ? ", filtercondition];

this above query only display data when we write full name.

i want if 'a' is like keyword then all name with 'a' should fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *searchfilter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",@"a"];
strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM YuurTable where FirstName like[c] %@", searchfilter];
```

U can use "a" directly also in condition,

---

These bottom lines are may not use for u

```
 const char *sql = [strValue UTF8String];

    NSString *requireddata=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 3)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
 NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from FormData where flgActive=1 and FirstName like %@%%",prefixString];
```